# What's the standard interaction pattern for bulk edit / delete actions on windows phones?

Tags: mobile, design-patterns, windows-phone-7

I'm looking for the standard pattern for windows phone for bulk actions like delete, archive or move. I mean, for example: How is the user supposed to delete multiple items at once.

I couldn't find anything in the [Windows Phone Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915%28v=vs.92%29)

The known pattern for iOS is to have an edit button:

[image: iOS bulk action]

For Android it is to to a long press to select the one item:

[image: Android bulk action]

Is there a recommended pattern for Windows Phone, that is established? What is it?

Comment: Android apps also use a delete item on the context menu brought up with the phone's menu button to enter bulk delete. The app then offers checkboxes for the list items and a delete button at the top right. Cancelling the bulk action is simply done using the phone's "back/undo" button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out how the standard Windows Phone Mail application handles it.

Tap any mail item at the lefthand edge of the window - a column of checkboxes will slide into view, with the item you just tapped already selected.

The application bar will alter to show you the available bulk actions - *Delete* and *Move* are the two main options, with *Mark as Read*, *Mark as Unread*, *Set Flag*, *Complete* and *Clear Flag* listed below.

Here's a screenshot showing the checkboxes in use:

[image: Mail Multiselect]

Original webpage: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/people/email.aspx